# how to validate a manual input in the keyboarddatepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I want to validate the date, if the user is entering by typing and pasting as well. How can it be done?
I have gone through https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker , but was not able to find an answer to my question.
Found https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1335 , but not sure whether, it is application or not.